# Can I use C-1/D visa as a transit visa through the US?

Tags: air-travel, usa, transit-visas

I have a C-1/D visa valid until 2019, but I am not working on a cruise ship right now. I work at the Atlantis in Nassau, Bahamas. I want to travel to India via a US airport. Would I be able to use the C-1/D visa to transit through the USA, or do I need a separate transit visa to make the trip?

Comment: A C-1 visa *is* a transit visa.  A C-1/D visa is a combination visa that can be used either as a C-1 or as a D visa.  So you can use the C-1/D visa for transit; you do not need a separate visa to make the trip.